# Is there a way to change the color of the black pixels generated by georeferencing?

Tags: georeferencing, color, background

When I georeference, QGIS creates black pixels to fill the empty space caused by rotation. As a background, so to speak. How can I set it to be white pixels instead of black?

[image]

This is the *.tif i get as a result.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the pixel problem?

Comment: Did you look at this prior thread? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332324/qgis-raster-georeferencer-adds-black-padding-to-corners-of-adjusted-black-and-wh?rq=1

Comment: Thanks John. I Did not. That helps a lot.